# Raster issues: raster2pgsql constraints fail

Tags: raster, postgis, raster2pgsql

I am having an issue when loading the data in to postgis with this command:

```
raster2pgsql  -s 3020 -d -I -Y -C -R -N 0 -t auto -r -l 2 -F data.tiff table_rast_test | psql -U postgres -d db.
```

I get these messages:

```
NOTICE:  Unable to create coverage raster. Cannot add coverage tile constraint: rt_raster_new: Dimensions requested exceed the maximum (65535 x 65535) permitted for a raster (XX000)
WARNING:  Unable to add constraint: 'regular_blocking'.  Skipping
```

The rasters can be viewed in qgis.

Can I add these constraints in the postgres db? Or do I need to fix the dimensions issue first?

Comment: Have a try with `-t` https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader

Comment: Is -t for the tile size? I am trying after using gdal_translate to resize the image, seems to be working.

Comment: Now getting this error when importing the sql into postgres:          NOTICE:  Unable to create coverage raster. Cannot add coverage tile constraint: invalid memory alloc request size 18446744072196938280 (XX000)
psql:sql/loc.sql:53412: WARNING:  Unable to add constraint: 'regular_blocking'.  Skipping

Comment: @user30184 any comments?

Comment: You must tile your raster if it's too big to fit in one table row.

Comment: @PierreRacine I am getting the error even with -t 32x32.     `raster2pgsql -t 32x32 -d -I -Y -C -M -R -l 4 -F -r  [name_of_tiff] [name_of_table]`

Comment: Why do you use the -C option in the first place?

Comment: @PierreRacine I thought it was required. The constraints are not needed?

Comment: Only if you have a requirement for them. Otherwise they would not be an option of the command line tool. They would be implicit.

Comment: @PierreRacine Ok, thanks.